# How do I write the value of a single property of a object?

Tags: powershell, logfile, get-wmiobject, select-object

This is how my current script looks like:

```
$cpu = Get-WmiObject win32_processor | select LoadPercentage
logwrite $cpu #this fuction writes $cpu into a .txt file
```

The output of the file is:

```
@{LoadPercentage=4}
```

I want it to be only the number so that I can make calculations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is a pretty simple fix. Instead of selecting the `LoadPercentage` when running `Get-WmiObject`, just select the property when calling your function. This will write only the number to your log file.

```
$cpulogpath = "C:\Monitoring\$date.csv"
function logwrite
{
    param ([string]$logstring)
    add-content $cpulogpath -value $logstring
}

$cpu = Get-WmiObject win32_processor #don't select the property here
logwrite $cpu.LoadPercentage #select it here
```

Answer (score 15):

**[qbanet359's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48808121/45375) uses *direct property access*** (`.LoadPercentage`) on the result object, which is the simplest and most efficient solution in this case.

In PowerShell **v3+** this even works with **extracting property values from a *collection* (array, list) of objects**, via a feature called [*member-access enumeration*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375).

<sup>E.g., `((Get-Date), (Get-Date).AddYears(-1)).Year` returns `2019` and `2018` when run in 2019, which are the `.Year` property values from each `[datetime]` instance in the array.</sup>

---

In cases where you do want to use **`Select-Object`** (or its built-in alias, `select`), such as when **processing a *large* input collection *item by item***, so as to take advantage of potentially memory-friendly *streaming* processing:

**To use `Select-Object` to extract a single property *value*, you must use `-ExpandProperty`**:

```bash
Get-WmiObject win32_processor | Select-Object -ExpandProperty LoadPercentage
```

As [zett42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7571258/zett42) notes, **using [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/ForEach-Object) with [simplified syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Simplified_Syntax) is another option**, which, when using the built-in `%` alias makes for a concise solution that is handy for interactive use:

```bash
# Short for: ForEach-Object -MemberName LoadPercentage
# which in turn is equivalent to: ForEach-Object { $_.LoadPercentage }
Get-WmiObject win32_processor | % LoadPercentage
```

- As an aside re performance (probably won't matter in most cases): Surprisingly,
  `ForEach-Object -MemberName LoadPercentage` is *slower* than
  `ForEach-Object { $_.LoadPercentage }`, up to at least PowerShell 7.3.4 (the current version as of this writing); see [GitHub issue #7700](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7700).

---

##### Background information:

[`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) by default creates *custom objects* (`[pscustomobject]` instances<sup>[1]</sup>
) that have the properties you specify via the `-Property` parameter (optionally implicitly, as the 1st *positional* argument).

This applies even when specifying a *single* property<sup>[2]</sup>, so that `select LoadPercentage` (short for: `Select-Object -Property LoadPercentage`) creates something like the following object:

```bash
$obj = [pscustomobject] @{ LoadPercentage = 4 } # $obj.LoadPercentage yields 4
```

Because you use `Add-Content` to write to your log file, it is the `.ToString()` string representation of that custom object that is written, as you would get if you used the object in an expandable string (try  `"$([pscustomobject] @{ LoadPercentage = 4 })"`).

By contrast, parameter `-ExpandProperty`, which can be applied to a *single* property only, does *not* create a custom object and instead returns the *value* of that property from the input object.

- Note: If the value of that property happens to be an *array* (collection), its elements are output *individually*; that is, you'll get *multiple* outputs per input object.

---

<sup>[1] Strictly speaking, they're `[System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject]` instances, whereas type accelerator `[pscustomobject]`, confusingly, refers to type `[System.Management.Automation.PSObject]`, for historical reasons; see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4344).</sup>

<sup>[2] There's a [hotly debated request on GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5237) to change `Select-Object`'s default behavior with only a single property; while the discussion is interesting, the current behavior is unlikely to change.</sup>