# Parsing import csv and iterating pipeline values

Tags: powershell

I have a function called `Get-InstalledApps` that connects to all computers listed with the `-computers` parameter, which accepts input via the pipeline.

There are two problems when piping computer names to the function:

(a) I have a CSV file I can pass to it but it parses the value like this: `@{computername=HOSTNAME}` instead of just `HOSTNAME`.

(b) When piping from `Get-ADComputer -Filter *` instead, it's only grabbing the last computer name passed.

Here's my function:

```
function Get-InstalledApps {

    Param (

    [CmdletBinding()]

    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]

    [Alias('name')]

    [string[]]$computers = $env:COMPUTERNAME

    )

    foreach($computer in $computers){

        write-verbose -verbose -message "`nStarting scan on $computer"

        Invoke-Command -Computername $computer -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable InvokeError -Scriptblock  {

            $installPaths = @('HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall','HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall')

            Get-ChildItem -Path $installPaths | Get-ItemProperty | Sort-Object -Property DisplayName | Select-Object -Property DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, UninstallString, Version

        }

        if ($invokeerror){

                Write-Warning "Could not communicate with $computer"

        }

    }

}
```

Update: This issue has been resolved. Here is the gist for those who want it:

https://gist.github.com/TylerJWhit/f596c307cf87540842281a8a20149f9a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re (a):

If your function sees `@{computername=HOSTNAME}` instead of just `HOSTNAME`, the implication is that you're doing something like:

```
 Import-Csv ... | Select-Object ComputerName | Get-InstalledApps
```

instead of the required:

```
 Import-Csv ... | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ComputerName | Get-InstalledApps
```

Note the `-ExpandProperty` switch, which is required in order to extract a single property *value* from the input; without it, you'll get an *object with that property* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48809321/45375) for more.

---

Re (b):

In order to accept *object-by-object* pipeline input, your function must have a `process { ... }` block:

```
function Get-InstalledApps {
  Param (
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
    [Alias('name')]
    [string[]]$computers = $env:COMPUTERNAME
  )

  process {  # This ensures that the following code is called for each input object.
    foreach ($computer in $computers){
      # ...
    }
  }

}
```

See [`Get-Help about_Functions_Advanced`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced).

Note that if you only ever expect your function to receive the list of computer names via the *pipeline* (`... | Get-InstalledApps`) as opposed to *by parameter* (`Get-InstalledApps -Computers ...`), you can declare the `-Computers` parameter as just `[string]` (not as an *array*), which obviates the need for the `foreach` loop inside the `process { ... }` block.
For a discussion of this difference, see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4242).