# Select-Object output directly to a variable

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm putting together a script to go to a bunch of domain computers and copy a file.

My code is:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path \\$computer -Filter $filename -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object Directory -outvariable $directory
```

Now my problem is the result that is stored in the variable is `@{Directory=\\Computer\dir`

How do i make it output to the variable only the `\\Computer\dir`

Any help or guidance would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In essence, your problem is a duplicate of [How do I write the value of a single property of a object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48807857/how-do-i-write-the-value-of-a-single-property-of-a-object) (among others) - in short: **use `-ExpandProperty <propName>` instead of just `[-Property] <propName>`** in order to extract just the property *value*, rather than creating a *custom object with a property of that name*.

Additionally, your problem is that you **must pass a mere variable *name* - without the `$` sigil - to 
`-OutVariable`**:

```
Select-Object -ExpandProperty Directory -OutVariable directory
```

That is, pass just `directory` to `-OutVariable` to have it fill variable `$directory`.
By contrast, `-OutVariable $directory` would fill a variable whose name is *contained* in variable `$directory`.

Answer (score 1):

`Select-Object` by default creates an object that has the properties you selected. So in your case you get an object with a single property called `Directory`. If you are only selecting a single property you can use the `ExpandProperty` parameter to "promote", for lack of a better word, a property to an object.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path \\$computer -Filter $filename -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue `
| Select-Object -ExpandProperty Directory -OutVariable directory
```

Comment: I tried that but it still gives me the same information in the variable

Comment: The `Directory` property is not a basic value type, it is also an object with properties. Try `-ExpandProperty FullName` instead and see if that gives you what you are looking for.

Comment: Yeah its still doing the same thing. Maybe this is just the only format of output i can get in to the variable

I get 
@{Directory=\\Computer\Dir}

What I want is
\\Computer\Dir

Maybe i have to convert the variable in to another variable dropping the unwanted information?

Comment: The problem is that `-outvariable $directory` should be `-outvariable directory`