# Powershell: indexOf row where column = searchstring

Tags: arrays, powershell, indexof

I have a table $t (an imported csv) with several columns. The first header is 'A'.
I want to know the number (index) of the row where the value in column 'A' equals the searchstring $s (without using a loop).

So I found `[array]::indexOf(<1-dimensional-array>,<searchString>)`
In order to use this, I need to create a 1-dimensional array from column 'A'.
I tried `$a = @($t | select A)` and then I can address each element like `$a[0]` or `$a[3]`. So does this qualify as an one-dimensional-array in the context of indexOf?
When I set the search string $s to a value that is present, then
`[array]::indexOf($a,$s)` always returns -1.

Comment: In short: [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) (`select`) returns _a `[pscustomobject]` instance_ that has the _requested properties_ - even when you're only asking for a _single_ property. To get only that property's _value_, use `-ExpandProperty <propertyName>` instead - see the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48809321/45375) for details and alternatives.

Comment: As an aside: The `IndexOf()` method is case-_sensitive_, whereas PowerShell's native features are by default case-_insensitive_.

Comment: Thank you, that worked right away: $a = @($t | select -expandProperty A). As an aside: what would a native Powershell feature be for this task ( [array]::indexOf ) ? - Ok, got .LastIndexOf()

Comment: Glad to hear it. Unfortunately, there are  currently no PowerShell-native equivalents to `IndexOf()` / `LastIndexOf()`