# Cannot compare two variables in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am using Powershell and I am trying to compare the free space of a drive to the size of files I want to put onto the drive, but it doesn't seem to like the comparison and I get the error below. I'm wondering if the name preceding each value is causing the issue. If this is the case, is there a way to properly compare these values while retaining the name, or would I have to store the named values as a separate variable?

```
Cannot compare "@{Zipped Space (GB)=65.6897087870166}" to "@{Free Space (GB)=-19.7659684484825}" because the objects are not the
same type or the object "@{Zipped Space (GB)=65.6897087870166}" does not implement "IComparable".
At G:\ManuallyCopyFiles.ps1:31 char:8
+ while ($zippedSize -gt $freeSpace)
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ExtendedTypeSystemException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PSObjectCompareTo
```

---

```
$freeSpace = (Get-ChildItem -Path "\\filler\C$\Users\filler\blah\" -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum |
Select-Object @{Name="Free Space (GB)";Expression={465-$_.Sum/1gb}})

$zippedSize = (Get-ChildItem -Path $dest -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum |
Select-Object @{Name="Zipped Space (GB)";Expression={0+$_.Sum/1gb}})

#Checks to see if there is enough space for the zipped files; if not, it deletes the oldest folder until there is enough space.

while ($zippedSize -gt $freeSpace)
{
    Get-ChildItem $remotePath | Sort CreationTime | Select -First 1 | Remove-Item

    $freeSpace = (Get-ChildItem -Path "\\filler\C$\Users\filler\blah\" -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
    Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum |
    Select-Object @{Name="Free Space (GB)";Expression={465-$_.Sum/1gb}})
}
```

Comment: Seems like you need `$zippedSize.'Zipped Space (GB)' -gt $freeSpace.'Free Space (GB)'` since those properties have the values you want to compare.

Answer (score 1):

[AdminOfThings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11025476/adminofthings) correctly points out that **you need to access the *properties* on the (single-property custom) *objects* you're creating** in order to compare the *numbers* of interest; to quote from his comment: `$zippedSize.'Zipped Space (GB)' -gt $freeSpace.'Free Space (GB)'`

Without that, you're trying to compare two objects of type `[pscustomobject]`, which aren't comparable<sup>[1]</sup>, resulting in the error you're seeing; a simple repro of the error condition:

```
# FAILS, because two [pscustomobject] instances cannot be compared with 
#    -gt / -ge / -lt / -le
# (and not meaningfully with -eq / -ne, which doesn't fail, but tests
#  *reference equality*, i.e. only if the operands are the *very same instance*).
[pscustomobject] @{ foo = 1 } -gt [pscustomobject] @{ foo = 2 }
```

Generally, to make [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) output just a *value*, you must use the `-ExpandProperty` parameter, even if you're only selecting *one* property - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48809321/45375).

However, in your case, where you're creating a *calculated* property, it seems that you don't need an intermediate object at all and therefore don't need `Select-Object`- **just use an *expression* to calculate the values (numbers) of interest**:

```sh
$freeSpace = 465 - (Get-ChildItem -Path "\\filler\C$\Users\filler\blah" -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
                      Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum).Sum / 1gb

$zippedSize = (Get-ChildItem -Path $dest -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
                Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum).Sum / 1gb
```

---

<sup>[1] For an object to be comparable to other objects of the same or, thanks to PowerShell's automatic type conversions, compatible types, its type must implement the [`System.IComparable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IComparable) or interface or its generic equivalent, [`System.IComparable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IComparable-1). Both interfaces have just one method, named `Convert`, which indicates whether the two objects being compared are equal or a less-than or greater-than relationship.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not really dealing with Zipped files the variable names are misleading to say the least (Get-ChildItem can not read the contents of zipped files).

You may want something more like this:

```
$Src = '\\ComputerMentor2\CMShared\NAS-Downloads\'
$Files = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $Src -File -Recurse
$Size = 0
ForEach ($File in $Files) { $Size += $File.Length}

"There were $($Files.Count) files found.`nConsisting of $Size bytes"
```

Sample Output:

```
There were 70 files found.
Consisting of 2819056460 bytes
```

This will give you a byte count which you can then convert to any other measurement you wish.

Since you are trying to see if the files will fit on a drive you may want to round the individual file sizes up to the nearest sector boundary since that is the space they will consume on the drive when actually copied.