# How can I pull the value in Command in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I want to learn the powershell version and write conditions accordingly, but I couldn't do it as I wanted.

```
"(Get-Host).Version | Select-Object major"
```

Output:

```
Major
-----
5
```

When I use the command, I guess it doesn't work because it shows as value under major. How can I get the value?

I tried something like this so I can get it as True or False, but it didn't work. It always returns false

```
if ( "(Get-Host).Version | Select-Object major" -eq "5" ) 
{ 
echo "True" 
} 
else 
{ 
echo "False"
 }
```

Output:

```
false
```

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48809321/45375) may also be of interest - it discusses various ways of extracting a single property _value_ from command output; if you use `Select-Object` (not really necessary in your case), you must use `Select-Object -ExpandProperty major`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace

**THIS**

```
if ( "(Get-Host).Version | Select-Object major" -eq "5" ) 
{ 
echo "True" 
} 
else 
{ 
echo "False"
 }
```

**With This:**

```
if ( ((Get-Host).Version).Major -eq "5" ) 
{ 
echo "True" 
} 
else 
{ 
echo "False"
 }
```

**Note:** `Get-Host` is just the PS Host version. It might not be the PS Engine version. The engine version comes from `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion`. So, my recommendation for you is to use `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major` instead of `(((Get-Host).Version).Major)`

Answer (score 2):

An object of the type [System.Version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.version?view=net-6.0) is like any other object, it's properties can be referenced by `.PropertyName`

> The most common way to get the values of the properties of an object is to use the dot method. Type a reference to the object, such as a variable that contains the object, or a command that gets the object. Then, type a dot (.) followed by the property name.

From [about_Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_properties?view=powershell-7.2#:%7E:text=Properties%20are%20the%20data%20that,False%20if%20it%20does%20not.)

---

```
PS /> $ver = [version]'1.0.1'
PS /> $ver

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
1      0      1      -1

PS /> $ver.Major -eq 1
True

PS /> $ver | Get-Member -MemberType Property

   TypeName: System.Version

Name          MemberType Definition
----          ---------- ----------
Build         Property   int Build {get;}
Major         Property   int Major {get;}
MajorRevision Property   short MajorRevision {get;}
Minor         Property   int Minor {get;}
MinorRevision Property   short MinorRevision {get;}
Revision      Property   int Revision {get;}
```

The condition would be:

```
if((Get-Host).Version.Major -eq 5)
{
    'True'
}
else
{
    'False'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The version is already in the `$PSVersionTable` variable.

```
PS C:\> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Patch  PreReleaseLabel BuildLabel
-----  -----  -----  --------------- ----------
7      2      0

PS C:\> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major
7
```