# How to check for value in powershell cmdlet output?

Tags: powershell

Please explain how I can check the output of the value `DynamicPortRangeStartPort` in the `get-nettcpsetting` cmdlet.

The output looks like this:

```
get-nettcpsetting | select DynamicPortRangeStartPort

DynamicPortRangeStartPort
-------------------------
                         
1024                     
1024                     
1024                     
1024                     
1024
```

The cmdlet returns an array of settings, and I just want to check if `DynamicPortRangeStartPort` is the value `1024` on any of the returned items.

I'm not sure what I'm missing.

I've tried:

```
if ((get-nettcpsetting | Select DynamicPortRangeStartPort)[1] -eq 1024) { write-host "Yes" }
(get-nettcpsetting | select DynamicPortRangeStartPort) -contains "1024"
(get-nettcpsetting | select DynamicPortRangeStartPort) -in "1024"
(get-nettcpsetting | select DynamicPortRangeStartPort).Contains(1024)
(get-nettcpsetting | select DynamicPortRangeStartPort).Contains("1024")
```

Forgive my ignorance...

Comment: `Where-Object` is your friend :) `if(Get-NetTCPSetting |Where DynamicPortRangeStartPort -eq 1024){ ... }`

Comment: In short: [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) (`select`) by default returns _a `[pscustomobject]` instance_ that has the _requested properties_ - even when you're only asking for a _single_ property. To get only that property's _value_, use `-ExpandProperty <propertyName>` instead - see the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48809321/45375) for details and alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

I discovered that `Select DynamicPortRangeStartPort` returns an array of objects with exactly one property (`DynamicPortRangeStartPort`).

Instead, I can use `Select -ExpandProperty DynamicPortRangeStartPort` to generate a stream of values, rather than a stream of objects with a property.

```
if ((get-nettcpsetting | Select -Expandproperty DynamicPortRangeStartPort) -contains (1024)) { write-host "Yes" }
```

As mentioned in a comment, `Where-Object` also works:

```
if(Get-NetTCPSetting | Where DynamicPortRangeStartPort -eq 1024){ Write-Host "Yes" }
```

Comment: Given that it's an array, you can use other operators like `-eq`, `-match`, etc., and it should work the same.