# Powershell Select and Use Specific Value

Tags: powershell

I am preparing a script. What I want to do is to get the user SID from Active Directory and use it in another command.

I tried to do this command but couldn't run it

```
$username = Read-Host -Prompt 'Erdem.OV'
$SID = Get-ADUser -Identity $username | select-object SID
$PSExec = "C:\Windows\System32\PsExec.exe"
$hostname = Read-Host -Prompt 'hostname'

$command = 'cmd /c "reg add "HKEY_USERS\"$SID"\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Control Panel" /v ConnectionsTab /t REG_DWORD /d 0"'

Start-Process -Filepath "$PsExec" -ArgumentList "\\$hostname $command"
```

Thanks.

Comment: What happened? Did your wrist cramp? Did your computer catch on fire? Or did you actually manage to run the code, but it threw an error? If it's the latter, please post the error message :)

Comment: `... |select-object -ExpandProperty SID`?

Comment: Hi, there is no error message. :) But it didn't work

Comment: Most frequent powershell question ever.

Comment: In short: [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) (`select`) by default returns _a `[pscustomobject]` instance_ that has the _requested properties_ - even when you're only asking for a _single_ property. To get only that property's _value_, use `-ExpandProperty $propertyName` instead - see the [linked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48807857/45375) for details and alternatives, notably the ability to simply use `(...).$propertyName`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked like this. :)

```
$username = Read-Host -Prompt 'Username'
$SID = (Get-ADUser -Identity $username).sid.value
$PSExec = "C:\Windows\System32\PsExec.exe"
$hostname = Read-Host -Prompt 'hostname'

$command = 'cmd /c'
$command2 = '"reg add "HKEY_USERS\'
$command3 = '\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Control Panel" /v ConnectionsTab /t REG_DWORD /d 0"'

Start-Process -Filepath "$PsExec" -ArgumentList "\\$hostname $command $command2$SID$command3"
```

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

simply do this:

```
(Get-ADUser -Identity $username).sid.value
```

Comment: Thanks, script still not working and there is no error message but it gives the true value. 

I guess it's not copy to the right location in the $SID path.

"HKEY_USERS\"$SID"\SOFTWARE\