# Foreach/copy-item based on name contains

Tags: powershell, foreach, copy-item

I'm trying to create a list of file name criteria (MS Hotfixes) then find each file name containing that criteria in a directory and copy it to another directory. I think I'm close here but missing something simple.

Here is my current attempt:

```
#Create a list of the current Hotfixes.
Get-HotFix | Select-Object HotFixID | Out-File "C:\Scripts\CurrentHotfixList.txt"
#
#Read the list into an Array (dropping the first 3 lines).
$HotfixList = Get-Content "C:\Scripts\CurrentHotfixList.txt" | Select-Object -Skip 3
#
#Use the Hotfix names and copy the individual hotfixes to a folder
ForEach ($Hotfix in $HotfixList) {
        Copy-Item -Path "C:\KBtest\*" -Include *$hotfix* -Destination "C:\KBtarget"
}
```

If I do a Write-Host $Hotfix and comment out my Copy-Item line I get the list of hotfixes as expected.

If I run just the copy command and input the file name I am looking for - it works.

```
Copy-Item -Path "C:\KBtest\*" -Include *kb5016693* -Destination "C:\KBtarget"
```

But when I run my script it copies all the files in the folder and not just the one file I am looking for. I have several hotfixes in that KBtest folder but only one that is correct for testing.

What am I messing up here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **simplest solution** to your problem, taking advantage of the fact that `-Include` can accept an *array* of patterns:

```
# Construct an array of include patterns by enclosing each hotfix ID
# in *...*
$includePatterns = (Get-HotFix).HotfixID.ForEach({ "*$_*" })

# Pass all patterns to a single Copy-Item call.
Copy-Item -Path C:\KBtest\* -Include $includePatterns -Destination C:\KBtarget
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

To save just the hotfix IDs to a plain-text file, each on its own line, use the following, don't use `Select-Object -Property HotfixId` (`-Property` is implied if you omit it), use  `Select-Object -ExpandProperty HotfixId`:

```
Get-HotFix | Select-Object -ExpandProperty HotFixID | Out-File "C:\Scripts\CurrentHotfixList.txt"
```

Or, more simply, using [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration):

```
(Get-HotFix).HotFixID > C:\Scripts\CurrentHotfixList.txt
```

Using `Select-Object -ExpandProperty HotfixID` or `(...).HotfixID` returns only the *values* of the `.HotfixID` properties, whereas `Select-Object -Property HotfixId` - despite only asking for *one* property - returns an *object that has a `.HotfixID` property* - this is a common pitfall; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48809321/45375) for more information.

Then you can use a `Get-Content` call alone to read the IDs (as strings) back into an array (no need for `Select-Object -Skip 3`):

```
$HotfixList = Get-Content "C:\Scripts\CurrentHotfixList.txt"
```

(Note that, as the solution at the top demonstrates, for use in the same script you don't need to save the IDs to a *file* in order to capture them.)

This will likely fix your primary problem, which stems from how [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file) creates *for-display* string representations of the *objects* (`[pscustomobject]` instances) that `Select-Object -Property HotfixID` created:

Not only is there an empty line followed by a table header at the *start* of the output (which your `Select-Object -Skip 3` call skips), there are also *two empty lines* at the *end*.

When these empty lines were read into `$hotfix` in your `foreach` loop, `-Include *$hotfix*` effectively became `-Include **`, which therefore copied *all* files.

Comment: That got it! Thanks for the help and for the explanation.  I thought it had something to do with formatting of that file but couldn't put my finger on exactly what was wrong.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped, @Dave_1972; my pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

first, you do not need to create and import those textfiles:

```
get-hotfix | ?{$_.hotfixid -notmatch 'KB5016594|KB5004567|KB5012170'} | %{
    copy-item -path "C:\kbtest\$($_.HotfixId).exe" -Destination "C:\kbTarget"
}
```

This filters for the hotfixes you do not want, if you do not need it remove:

```
?{$_.hotfixid -notmatch 'KB5016594|KB5004567|KB5012170'}
```

I assume that those files are exe files in my example.