# powershell script to populate uidnumber problem with conversion to systm.Int32 value

Tags: powershell, integer, posix

i'm trying to write a script to popolate uidnumber in active directory.

```
$SearchBase = "OU=test,DC=xxx,DC=local"
$lastuid = Get-ADUser -Filter * -searchbase $searchbase -Properties * | Where {($_.uidNumber -ne $null)} | select uidnumber | Measure-Object -Property uidnumber -Maximum | select maximum | 
Format-Wide
$i= $lastuid
$nouid = Get-ADUser -Filter * -searchbase $searchbase -Properties * | Where {($_.uidNumber -eq $null)} | select samaccountname
$nouid | %{Set-ADUser $_.samAccountName -add @{uidnumber=('{0:D4}' -f $i++)}}
```

This do not produce error but pupulate uidnumber starting from 0, ignoring lastuid.
If i use

```
$i= $lastuid
```

produce error like

```
    "Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type "System.Int32". At C:\-\Documents\uid.ps1:16 char:15...  $nouid | %{Set-ADUser $_.samAccountName -replace @{uidnumber=([int]  ...
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
 FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConvertToFinalInvalidCastException"
```

any suggestion?

Comment: Thank you very much!!
 in this way, seems work 

#scope 
$SearchBase = "OU=test,DC=cncs,DC=local"

#get people 
$withoutUid, $withtUid = 
  (Get-ADUser -Filter * -searchbase $searchbase -Properties uidnumber).
  Where({ $null -eq $_.uidnumber }, 'Split')

#get last uidnumber assigned
[int] $lastuid = (
 $withtUid | 
  Measure-Object -Property uidnumber -Maximum
).Maximum

  #set uidnumber
  $withoutUid | %{Set-ADUser $_.samAccountName -replace @{uidnumber= [int] ++$lastuid }} 

Now i have to integrate some operations on GID attribute ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your command that determines the currently highest uidNumber is broken**; replace it with the following:

```bash
[int] $lastuid = (
  Get-ADUser -Filter * -searchbase $searchbase -Properties uidnumber | 
  Measure-Object -Property uidnumber -Maximum
).Maximum
```

Note:

- `(...).Maximum`, i.e. direct property access is used to obtain the maximum value from the `Measure-Object` call.

  - There is no need for `select` (`Select-Object`), and especially not `Format-Wide` - see next section.
- There's no need for filtering out `$null` values with a `Where` (`Where-Object`) call, as `Measure-Object` will simply ignore them.
- Using `-Properties *` is expensive and best avoided; here, you only need one non-default property, `uidnumber`.

---

A separate problem is that **your code for updating the `uidnumber` field doesn't increment the number *for each targeted user***: `[int] $i + 1` assigns the *same* value to all; the simplest solution is to use `++`:

```bash
$noUid | Set-ADUser -replace @{ uidnumber = ++$i }
```

Note:

- There is no need for `%` (`ForEach-Object`), as you can pipe the user objects stored in `$noUid` *directly* to `Set-ADUser`.

---

There's potential for additional **optimization of your code**, such as calling `Get-ADUser -Filter *` only once, assuming that all users objects fit into memory at once:

```bash
$withoutUid, $withtUid = 
  (Get-ADUser -Filter * -searchbase $searchbase -Properties uidnumber).
  Where({ $null -eq $_.uidnumber }, 'Split')

[int] $lastuid = ($withUid | Measure-Object -Property uidnumber -Maximum).Maximum

$withoutUid | Set-ADUser -replace @{ uidnumber = ++$lastuid }
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

- `Format-*` cmdlets such as `Format-Wide` emit output objects whose sole purpose is to provide *formatting instructions* to PowerShell's for-display output-formatting system. In short: only ever use `Format-*` cmdlets to format data *for display*, never for subsequent *programmatic processing* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55174715/45375) for more information.

  - Apart from `Format-Wide` not representing the *data* you intended, it output *multiple* objects, which `$lastuid = ...` captured in an *array*. It is that array that caused the error you saw.
- Omitting `Format-Wide` wouldn't suffice in your case, because `select maximum` (`Select-Object maximum`) also wouldn't work as intended: it would create an *object* with a `.Maximum` property, instead of directly emitting the *value* of the `.Maximum` property of the property returned by `Measure-Object`. For the latter you need `Select-Object -ExpandProperty maximum` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48807857/45375) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Option

```
$withoutUid | Set-ADUser -replace @{ uidnumber = ++$lastuid }
```

did not work for me: all user accounts with no uidNumber got the same 1+$lastuid. I.e. if I am running the script on OU where no users has uidNumber - all of them are getting uidNumber=1

### Solution

The resulting script is less optimized, but works fine with me:

```
$SearchBase = "OU=test,DC=my,DC=domain,DC=local"
$withoutUid, $withtUid = 
  (Get-ADUser -Filter * -searchbase $searchbase -Properties uidnumber).
  Where({ $null -eq $_.uidnumber }, 'Split')


 #Getting last uid intact

 [int] $lastuid = (
  Get-ADUser -Filter * -searchbase $searchbase -Properties uidnumber | 
  Measure-Object -Property uidnumber -Maximum
  ).Maximum

$i = $lastuid+1


 #Setting up UID one by one.
 foreach ($user in $withoutuid) {            
 #Search in specified OU and Update existing attributes            
  Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$($user.samaccountname)'" |          
  Set-ADUser -Replace  @{ uidnumber = $i++ }            
}
```