# How to work with an object array in powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell

I'd like to create a powershell script to show which network interface is down from the get-vmswitchteam and get-netadapter output comparison.

What I'd like to achieve:

1. Check the name of the Get-VMSwitchTeam members
2. Check those names are up or down in the output of the get-netadapter
3. If not up, alert

However I can't refer to the object inside the array so I can't compare the values between the get-netadapter and get-vmswitchteam.
I've used to use the Get-NetLbfoTeamMember but this doesn't have any output in my new system.

This is the adapters in the teaming:

```
$adapters=(Get-VMSwitchTeam -Name "Teaming"|Select-Object NetAdapterInterfaceDescription)
$adapters

NetAdapterInterfaceDescription
------------------------------
{HPE FlexFabric 10Gb 4-port 536FLR-T Adapter #4, HPE FlexFabric 10Gb 4-port 536FLR-T Adapter #2}
```

One interface is down (disabled):

```
get-netadapter

Name                      InterfaceDescription                    ifIndex Status       MacAddress             LinkSpeed
----                      --------------------                    ------- ------       ----------             ---------
Embedded FlexibleLOM ...2 HPE FlexFabric 10Gb 4-port 536FLR-...#2      10 Disabled     08-xxx-62        10 Gbps
Embedded FlexibleLOM ...1 HPE FlexFabric 10Gb 4-port 536FLR-...#4      11 Up           08-xxx-60        10 Gbps
```

If I use

```
$adapters -split ","
```

I got this which is not the name of interface:

```
@{NetAdapterInterfaceDescription=System.String[]}
```

How can I get the list of the interfaces in get-vmswitchteam that I can use with some if statement  to compare with get-netadapter?

If I try to refer to the object in the array like $adapters[1] ... it shows the character at that position which I guess okay, but that is not I'd like to achieve.

Thank you for your help

Comment: How about `$adapters.NetAdapterInterfaceDescription -split "," ` ?

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much, this is what I want! Can you explain very briefly why this is the solution? I don't get why need double time to filter :/

Comment: Use the [Array subexpression operator `@()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#array-subexpression-operator--) to also force an array that contains only one element: `@($adapters)[1]`

Comment: [`Select-Object`](https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) (`select`) by default returns _a `[pscustomobject]` instance_ that has the _requested properties_ - even when you're only asking for a _single_ property. To get only that property's _value_, use `-ExpandProperty $propertyName` instead - see the [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48807857/45375) for details and alternatives, notably the ability to simply use `(...).$propertyName`

Comment: In other words: use `$adapters=(Get-VMSwitchTeam -Name "Teaming").NetAdapterInterfaceDescription`

Comment: Best way I found is to cast object to correct type by using ForEach  : $myArray.ForEach([new type]).

Comment: @iRon Arrays starts at [0]. Isn't that what should be used?

Comment: @Dennis that doesn't work, it gives back the same

Comment: @mklement0 perfect this too