# Powershell Registry String to Workable Date

Tags: powershell, datetime, registry, datetime-format

Cannot convert string format to date using parse exact.

Registry contains the following string value:
`2022-10-18T12:40:25`

I need to convert this string to a date field in order to count number of days since (compared to today).

```
$startdate = 
  Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:SOFTWARE\Adobe\Acrobat Distiller\DC\Installer\' |
  select-object 'Dummy'


[datetime]::parseexact($startdate,'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm',$null)

$today = (([datetime]::Now))
$x = New-TimeSpan -Start $startdate -End $today
"$($x.days) $("days have passed since") $($startdate)"
```

```
Cannot find an overload for "parseexact" and the argument count: "3".
At line:2 char:1
+ [datetime]::parseexact($startdate,'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm',$null)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest
 
New-TimeSpan : Cannot bind parameter 'Start'. Cannot convert value "@{dummy=2022-10-18T12:40:25}" to type "System.DateTime". Error: "Cannot convert the "@{dummy=2022-10-18T12:40:25}" value of type 
"Selected.System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject" to type "System.DateTime"."
At line:5 char:26
+ $x = New-TimeSpan -Start $startdate -End $today
+                          ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-TimeSpan], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewTimeSpanCommand
 
 days have passed since @{dummy=2022-10-18T12:40:25}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ***primary* problem** is that **you need to use `-ExpandProperty`**, if you use `Select-Object`, or you can use simple property access:

- [`Select-Object`](https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) (`select`) by default returns *a `[pscustomobject]` instance* that has the *requested properties* - even when you're only asking for a *single* property. To get only that property's *value*, use the `-ExpandProperty` parameter instead of the (possibly positionally implied) `-Property` parameter - see  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48807857/45375) for details and alternatives, notably the ability to simply use `(...).SomeProperty`

Therefore, the simplest solution is:

```
$startdate = (
  Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:SOFTWARE\Adobe\Acrobat Distiller\DC\Installer'
).Dummy
```

Or, in PSv5+, using [`Get-ItemPropertyValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-itempropertyvalue):

```
$startdate =
  Get-ItemPropertyValue 'HKLM:SOFTWARE\Adobe\Acrobat Distiller\DC\Installer' Dummy
```

As for then **parsing the resulting *string* into a `[datetime]` instance**:

The format string you're passing to [`::ParseExact()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime.ParseExact), doesn't match your input string, and [TheMadTechnician's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74789461/45375) shows how to fix that (see this answer's bottom section for further considerations).

However, you can more simply use a **`[datetime]` *cast***, which **recognizes your string format *as-is***, irrespective of what culture is currently in effect:

```
[datetime] '2022-10-18T12:40:25'
```

In essence, PowerShell translates the above into the following [`::Parse()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime.Parse) call:

```
[datetime]::Parse('2022-10-18T12:40:25', [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)
```

---

*In general, for full robustness* **when using format strings**, it is **best to  *escape* `:`, `/`, and `.`** (if present) with `\`, so as **if they are to be interpreted *literally***, i.e by only matching *literally* during *parsing* and being included *literally* when formatting *output* (by default, they're considered *placeholders* for the target culture's separators):

```
[datetime]::ParseExact(
  '2022-10-18T12:40:25', 
  'yyyy-MM-ddTHH\:mm\:ss',  # \-escaping ensures literal matching
  [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture
)
```

Note: In this particular case, `[cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture` *alone* would be sufficient for robustness, given that this culture uses `:` as the time separator.

Answer (score 0):

You get an error because your second argument doesn't match the format of the datetime.

```
[datetime]::parseexact($startdate,'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss',$null)
```

Comment: Tried changing the format [datetime]::parseexact($startdate,'yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm',$null)

Comment: Cannot find an overload for "parseexact" and the argument count: "3".
At line:2 char:1
+ [datetime]::parseexact($startdate,'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss',$null)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest