# How to properly get System Model in PowerShell and set it as a parameter?

Tags: powershell, conditional-statements, boolean-logic

I need to use PowerShell to properly get the System Model of a PC and use the model number as a parameter so that I can run tasks specific to the model number.

My code is a little more complex due to the fact that some of the methods returns values like 'Not Available', 'To be filled by O.E.M.'or  'System Product Manufacturer' - in these instances I do not want the $Model parameter to be 'Not Available', 'To be filled by O.E.M.'or  'System Product Manufacturer'.

I have the following, but it doesn't work as desired

```
    $BaseBoardManufacturer = Get-WmiObject Win32_BaseBoard | Select Manufacturer
if ((-not ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($BaseBoardManufacturer))) -and ($BaseBoardManufacturer.Manufacturer -ne 'Not Available') -or ($BaseBoardManufacturer.Manufacturer -ne 'System manufacturer'))
    {
        [String]$Manufacturer = ($BaseBoardManufacturer.Manufacturer).ToString()
    }
    
    $ProductManufacturer = Get-WmiObject -Class:Win32_ComputerSystemProduct | select Vendor
    if ((-not ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($ProductManufacturer))) -and ($ProductManufacturer.Vendor -ne 'Not Available') -or ($ProductManufacturer.Vendor -ne 'System manufacturer') -or ($ProductManufacturer.Vendor -ne 'To be filled by O.E.M.'))
    {
        [String]$Manufacturer = ($ProductManufacturer.Vendor).ToString()
    }
    
    $SystemManufacturer = Get-WmiObject -Class:Win32_ComputerSystem | select Manufacturer
    if ((-not ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($SystemManufacturer))) -and ($SystemManufacturer.Manufacturer -ne 'Not Available') -or ($SystemManufacturer.Manufacturer -ne 'System manufacturer') -or ($SystemManufacturer.Manufacturer -ne 'To be filled by O.E.M.'))
    {
        [String]$Manufacturer = ($SystemManufacturer.Manufacturer).ToString()
    }
    
    $BaseBoardProduct = Get-WmiObject Win32_BaseBoard | Select Product
    if ((-not ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($BaseBoardProduct))) -and ($BaseBoardProduct.Product -ne 'Not Available'))
    {
        [String]$Model = ($BaseBoardProduct.Product).ToString()
    }
    
    $ProductVersion = Get-WmiObject -Class:Win32_ComputerSystemProduct | select Version
    if ((!($ProductVersion.Version -ne 'System Version')) -xor (!($ProductVersion.Version -ne 'To be filled by O.E.M.')) -and (-not ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($ProductVersion))))
    {
        [String]$Model = ($ProductVersion.Version).ToString()
    }
    
    $SystemModel = Get-WmiObject -Class:Win32_ComputerSystem | select Model
    if ((-not ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($SystemModel))) -and ($SystemModel.Model -ne 'System Product Name') -or ($SystemModel.Model -ne 'To be filled by O.E.M.'))
    {
        [String]$Model = ($SystemModel.Model).ToString()
    }
    
    $SystemManufacturer = Get-WmiObject -Class:Win32_ComputerSystem | select Manufacturer
    if ((-not ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($SystemManufacturer))) -and ($SystemManufacturer.Manufacturer -ne 'Not Available') -or ($SystemManufacturer.Manufacturer -ne 'System manufacturer') -or ($SystemManufacturer.Manufacturer -ne 'To be filled by O.E.M.'))
    {
        [String]$Manufacturer = ($SystemManufacturer.Manufacturer).ToString()
    }
    
    if ($Manufacturer -like '*Lenovo*')
    {
        $ProductVersion = Get-WmiObject -Class:Win32_ComputerSystemProduct | select Version
    [String]$Model = ($ProductVersion.Version).ToString()
    }
```

I want e.g.

```
    ((!($ProductVersion.Version -ne 'System Version')) -or (!($ProductVersion.Version -ne 'To be filled by O.E.M.')) -and (-not ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($ProductVersion))))
```

to return false when the ProductVersion returns 'To be filled by O.E.M.' or 'System Version', but it returns true!

I've tried

```
    ((!($ProductVersion.Version -ne 'System Version')) -xor (!($ProductVersion.Version -ne 'To be filled by O.E.M.')) -and (-not ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($ProductVersion))))
```

and

```
    if ((-not ($SystemModel.Model -eq 'System Product Name')) -or (-not ($SystemModel.Model -eq 'To be filled by O.E.M.')) -and (-not ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($SystemModel))))
```

but I get 'System Version' set as the parameter instead of the Model Number, in other words the argument returns true when it is supposed to return false

Comment: As an aside: The CIM cmdlets (e.g., `Get-CimInstance`) superseded the WMI cmdlets (e.g., `Get-WmiObject`) in PowerShell v3 (released in September 2012). Therefore, the WMI cmdlets should be avoided, not least because PowerShell (Core) v6+, where all future effort will go, doesn't even _have_ them anymore. Note that WMI still _underlies_ the CIM cmdlets, however. For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54508009/45375)

Comment: Allow me to give you a tip for future questions: There's more code in your question than is necessary to illustrate the problem, which creates a distraction and makes it harder to diagnose the problem. The best possible presentation of a problem is in the form of a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

- First, I suggest **simplifying your property retrieval commands**:

  - You're using [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) to extract a *single* property from the objects emitted by your `Get-WmiObject` calls
  - Perhaps surprisingly, something like `... | Select Product` (short for: `... | Select-Object -Property Product`) does *not* return the *values* of the input objects' `.Product` property, it returns a *new object* for each input object, which is of type `[pscustomobject]`and itself has a `Product` *property*.
  - **To only extract the property *values*, use [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object)'s `-ExpandProperty` parameter** instead of the (positionally implied) `-Property` parameter; e.g.

    **`... | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Product`**.
  - See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48807857/45375) for more information and more efficient alternatives.
- Second, there's a **problem with your Boolean logic**, explained in the next section.

However, I suggest **simplifying your conditional** as follows:

```bash
# Sample input objects.
@(
  $null
  [pscustomobject] @{ Version = $null }
  [pscustomobject] @{ Version = '' }
  [pscustomobject] @{ Version = 'System Version' }
  [pscustomobject] @{ Version = 'To be filled by O.E.M.' }
  [pscustomobject] @{ Version = '1' }

) | ForEach-Object {
  
  $ProductVersion = $_

  # Output $true only if $ProductVersion is an object that has 
  # a .Version property whose value is neither $null, the empty string
  # nor 'System Version' nor 'To be filled by O.E.M.'
  $ProductVersion.Version -notlike '' -and 
    $ProductVersion.Version -notin 'System Version', 'To be filled by O.E.M.'

}
```

- `$ProductVersion.Version -notlike ''` ensures that the `.Version` property value is neither `$null` nor the empty string (and even ensures that `$ProductVersion` itself is not `$null` (or the empty string, though that shouldn't happen in your case).
- The [`-notin`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-in-and--notin) operator offers a convenient way of testing whether the LHS string value isn't equal to *any* of the elements of the RHS array.

Output:

```bash
False
False
False
False
False
True
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

> ```bash
> ((!($ProductVersion.Version -ne 'System Version')) -or (!($ProductVersion.Version -ne 'To be filled by O.E.M.'))
> ```

This can be simplified to:

```bash
$ProductVersion.Version -eq 'System Version' -or $ProductVersion.Version -eq 'To be filled by O.E.M.'
```

and is the *opposite* of what you want, i.e. it returns `$true` if either of the string values are found.

You could negate the expression as a whole (`!` and [`-not`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Logical_Operators) are the *same* operator):

```bash
-not ($ProductVersion.Version -eq 'System Version' -or $ProductVersion.Version -eq 'To be filled by O.E.M.')
```

or use `-ne` instead of `-eq`, which requires you to change `-or` to `-and`:

```bash
$ProductVersion.Version -ne 'System Version' -and $ProductVersion.Version -ne 'To be filled by O.E.M.'
```

[`-xor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Logical_Operators), which returns true only if *exactly one* operand is `$true`, isn't called for here, because it requires evaluating *both* operands, which isn't necessary here.

Comment: I would love to do as you suggest, but my code needs to run in PowerShell in WinPE

Comment: @ArthurDurand, I've never used PowerShell in WinPE. What, specifically, from what this answer suggests, does _not_ work in WinPE, and why?

Comment: @ArthurDurand, another tip for the future: If you need to run in a specific environment, add the appropriate tag to your question, such as [tag:winpe] in this case.

Comment: @ArthurDurand, for the benefit of future readers: You state in a comment on your answer that the problem is that you cannot use CIM cmdlets in your WinPE environment. However, that is irrelevant to the solutions in this answer.

Answer (score -3):

```
    $BaseBoardProduct = Get-WmiObject Win32_BaseBoard | Where-Object {$_.Product -ne 'Not Available'} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Product
    if (-not ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($BaseBoardProduct)))
    {
        $Model = $BaseBoardProduct
    }
    
    $ProductVersion = Get-WmiObject -Class:Win32_ComputerSystemProduct | Where- Object {$_.Version -ne 'System Version' -and $_.Version -ne 'To be filled by O.E.M.'} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Version
    if (-not ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($ProductVersion)))
    {
        $Model = $ProductVersion
    }
    
    $SystemModel = Get-WmiObject -Class:Win32_ComputerSystem | Where-Object {$_.Model -ne 'System Product Name' -and $_.Model -ne 'To be filled by O.E.M.'} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Model
    if (-not ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($SystemModel)))
    {
        $Model = $SystemModel
    }
    
    $SystemManufacturer = Get-WmiObject -Class:Win32_ComputerSystem | Where- Object {$_.Manufacturer -ne 'Not Available' -and $_.Manufacturer -ne 'System manufacturer' -and $_.Manufacturer -ne 'To be filled by O.E.M.'} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Manufacturer
    if (-not ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($SystemManufacturer)))
    {
        $Manufacturer = $SystemManufacturer
    }
    
    if ($Manufacturer -like '*Lenovo*')
    {
        $ProductVersion = Get-WmiObject -Class:Win32_ComputerSystemProduct | 
Select-Object -ExpandProperty Version
        $Model = $ProductVersion
    }
```

solves my issue! However, **ChatGPT came up with**

```
$ExcludedManufacturers = 'Not Available', 'System Manufacturer', 'To be filled by O.E.M.'
$Filter = "Manufacturer!='Not Available' AND Manufacturer!='System Manufacturer' AND Manufacturer!='To be filled by O.E.M.'"

$SystemInfo = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem -Property Model, Manufacturer -Filter $Filter | Sort-Object Manufacturer
$BaseBoardProduct = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_BaseBoard -Property Product -Filter "Product!='Not Available'" | Sort-Object Product | Select-Object -First 1
$ProductVersion = $SystemInfo | Where-Object { $_.Version -notin 'System Version', 'To be filled by O.E.M.' } | Sort-Object Manufacturer | Select-Object -First 1 -ExpandProperty Version
$Model = ($BaseBoardProduct.Product, $SystemInfo.Model) | Where-Object { $_ -notin 'System Product Name', 'To be filled by O.E.M.' } | Select-Object -First 1
$Manufacturer = $SystemInfo[0].Manufacturer

if ($Manufacturer -like '*Lenovo*') {
    $Model = $ProductVersion
}
```

or

```
$BaseBoardProduct = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_BaseBoard | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Product | Where-Object {$_ -ne 'Not Available'} | Select-Object -First 1
$ProductVersion = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystemProduct | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Version | Where-Object {$_ -notin ('System Version', 'To be filled by O.E.M.')} | Select-Object -First 1
$SystemModel = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Model | Where-Object {$_ -notin ('System Product Name', 'To be filled by O.E.M.')} | Select-Object -First 1
$SystemManufacturer = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Manufacturer | Where-Object {$_ -notin ('Not Available', 'System Manufacturer', 'To be filled by O.E.M.')} | Select-Object -First 1

if ($SystemManufacturer -like '*Lenovo*') {
    $Model = $ProductVersion
} else {
    $Model = $BaseBoardProduct ?? $SystemModel ?? $ProductVersion
}
```

for older versions of PowerShell!

Comment: I've revived part of my original answer to explain the problem with not using `-ExpandProperty`. Your answer lacks an explanation, and it is missing the code that was your primary problem: the flawed logic of your conditionals (e.g. `((!($ProductVersion.Version -ne 'System Version')) -or (!($ProductVersion.Version -ne 'To be filled by O.E.M.')) -and (-not ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($ProductVersion))))`)

Comment: For the reasons stated, I'm down-voting, but I'm always happy to revisit based on a good-faith dialogue aimed at reaching a shared understanding. Of course, if _you_ feel that your answer is worth advertising as the solution to your problem, you should [self-accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) it, which you can do after 48 hours.

Comment: You did point me in the right direction, I would've loved to run with your suggestions, but like I said, WinPE doesn't support CimInstance!

Comment: Whether to use CIM vs. the WMI cmdlets is incidental to the solution. It also is no longer part of my answer, just an aside posted as a comment on the question now. To close this - inconsequential - tangent: It is interesting that the CIM cmdlets aren't available WinPE (which you hadn't mentioned before); I'm asking innocently: is this limitation documented somewhere?

Comment: And, leaving aside whether my answer solves your problem or not, please consider addressing the points I've made about why I think your answer won't be helpful to future readers.