# Remotely replace a string in a text file

Tags: powershell, scripting

I am trying to edit a file on multiple remote machines. I have a command that works locally, but when I try to invoke the command on a remote PC using administrator credentials I am getting an error.

This works locally:

```
(get-content -Path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Wycom\WyReceipts\WyReceiptsOverrides.ini') -replace ";End of WyReceipts Settings File",";Local Receipt Archive Directory
LocalPDFArchiveDirectory = C:\Program Files (x86)\WyCom\WyReceipts\LocalReceiptArchive

;End of WyReceipts Settings File" | Out-File -FilePath 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Wycom\WyReceipts\WyReceiptsOverrides.ini'
```

But when I try this i get errors:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$Credentials = Get-Credential
$Credentials.Password | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Set-Content C:\temp\password.txt
$Username = $Credentials.Username
$Password = Get-Content “C:\temp\password.txt” | ConvertTo-SecureString
$Credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $Username,$Password
Get-ADComputer -filter 'Name -like "ess-*-Tel*" -or Name -like "ess-*tel*" -and Enabled -eq "True"' | select "Name" | Out-File -FilePath "c:\Temp\WycomPCs.txt"
$computers = get-content -Path "c:\Temp\WycomPCs.txt"

ForEach ($computer in $computers){
Invoke-Command -Credential $Credentials -ScriptBlock {
(get-content -Path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Wycom\WyReceipts\WyReceiptsOverrides.ini') -replace ";End of WyReceipts Settings File",";Local Receipt Archive Directory
LocalPDFArchiveDirectory = C:\Program Files (x86)\WyCom\WyReceipts\LocalReceiptArchive

;End of WyReceipts Settings File" | Out-File -FilePath 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Wycom\WyReceipts\WyReceiptsOverrides.ini'
}}

Remove-Item -Path "C:\temp\password.txt"
```

Here is the error message I am receiving:

```
Invoke-Command : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At c:\mystuff\Scripts\WycomFix.ps1:11 char:1
+ Invoke-Command -Credential $Credentials -ScriptBlock {
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Command], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeCommandCommand
```

Is there a better way to go about this?
Thanks in advance!
-Bart (powershell novice, but getting better!)

Comment: Quick note: I thought maybe the out-file having the "name" header and trailing spaces may be causing issues, so i trimmed up the file, and commented out the Get-ADComputer line, but I still got the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You're missing a `-ComputerName $computer` argument in your [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/Invoke-Command) calls.

  - Omitting `-ComputerName` would make the calls *local* ones, but using `-Credential` is then *not* supported - and resulted in the error you saw; in other words: if you use `-Credential`, you must *also* use `-ComputerName`.<sup>[1]</sup>
- `-ComputerName` accepts an *array* of computers to target *in parallel*, which is much faster than targeting them *in sequence*, as in your `foreach` loop-based attempt.

Therefore, replace your `foreach` statement with this:

```bash
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computers -Credential $Credentials -ScriptBlock {

  (Get-Content -Path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Wycom\WyReceipts\WyReceiptsOverrides.ini') -replace ";End of WyReceipts Settings File",";Local Receipt Archive Directory
LocalPDFArchiveDirectory = C:\Program Files (x86)\WyCom\WyReceipts\LocalReceiptArchive

;End of WyReceipts Settings File" | Out-File -FilePath 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Wycom\WyReceipts\WyReceiptsOverrides.ini'

}
```

---

<sup>[1] Or one of the other parameters that target *other* computers, either remote ones or VMs. These requirements are enforced via [parameter sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parameter_Sets).</sup>

Comment: 1. Would I need to define $computers differently to be an array?  2. Would the above example eliminate the ForEach loop entirely? Thanks!

Comment: @BartHurley0283: Re 1. No, you can use `$computers` as-is, because when you capture `Get-Content` output, you automatically get an _array of lines_. Re 2. Yes, the above replaces your `foreach` loop (I've edited the answer to make that clear.)

Comment: That gave me a different error this time:  Invoke-Command : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ComputerName'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an 
argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.

+ Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computers -Credential $Credentials -Scr ...
+                              ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Invoke-Command], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeCommandCommand

Comment: @BartHurley0283 that implies that your `$computers` variable is either `$null`, the empty string or - if it is an array of values - _contains_ such entries. To rule out the latter case, try `-ComputerName (@($computers) -notlike '')`

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much. After reading the last comment I realized that when i trimmed up the file i didn't check for blank lines at the end of the list. Turns out there were a few there so the null error makes total sense! Thanks again as this was starting to baffle me. I'm fairly new to powershell scripting, but the more I do it the more uses I'm finding for it. I find myself approaching every problem now with the how can I fix this with powershell mindset.

Comment: One other quick question if you have a sec. I initially tried to eliminate the text list altogether by defining `$computers = Get-ADComputer -filter 'Name -like "ess-*-Tel*" -or Name -like "ess-*tel*" -and Enabled -eq "True"' | select "Name"` but this didn't work so I resorted to the txt file output and get-content. Is there a better way to eliminate the text file source list?

Comment: Glad to hear it, @BartHurley0283; my pleasure. PowerShell deserves the "power" part of its name, and time spent learning is well worth it, the occasional warts notwithstanding. As for your follow-up question: use `select -ExpandProperty Name` or `(...).Name` - see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48807857/45375) for details.

Comment: Sent you a coffee for your help. You rock!