# How to find necessary entry in registry via powershell script?

Tags: windows, powershell, registry, nvidia

I made a small PowerShell script that suppose to find uniquely named monitor folder in registry and then create a key in other pre-defined entry - https://github.com/SLStyler/Dithering-for-Windows-Simple-BAT-

These lines should define the right entry\path:

```
$DisplayPath = "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\DISPLAY" \\ This path should contain display "unique" name
$GetDisplay = Get-ChildItem -Path $DisplayPath -exclude Default* | Select-Object Name |Split-Path -Leaf
$GetDisplay = $GetDisplay.replace("}","")
$Path = "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\nvlddmkm\State\DisplayDatabase\" \\ This path should contain "unique" display identifier subkey and some other subkeys, so using $GetDisplay, script chooses the right one   
$GetFolder = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -include $GetDisplay* -recurse |Select-Object Name |Split-Path -Leaf
$GetFolder = $GetFolder.replace("}","")
```

It works perfectly fine on my system and this entry contains only two subentries\subkeys.

> Picture of $GetDisplay = HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\DISPLAY

[image]

**GSM5B55** is my display's "unique" name and just by excluding the "**Default_Monitor**", script finds the one needed.

But on some systems script shows error at launch because it cannot find the folder, either because there is more than one "uniquely" named subkey or none at all. (I don't know what it depends on but probably only Nvidia developer  can explain.)

In my case there is only one with the name of the monitor **GSM5B55...**, so script have no errors in deciding which subentry to use:

> Picture of $GetFolder = HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\nvlddmkm\State\DisplayDatabase\

[image]

This is a screenshot of a random guy's same path. I suppose in his case the unique display identifier is  **ACI27EC**. But for some reason my script doesn't work on his pc.

[image]

I'm absolutely out of ideas, and would be glad to receive any form of help, thank you

Comment: To mark text as comment in PowerShell, you need the `#` character, not a double backslash `\\\`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You must handle the following edge case:

  - There may be *only* a default monitor.
  - There may be *multiple* non-default monitors.
- Replace `Select-Object Name` with either `Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name` or, more simply, `ForEach-Object Name`.

  - [`Select-Object`](https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) (`select`) by default returns *a `[pscustomobject]` instance* that has the *requested properties* - even when you're only asking for a *single* property. The suggested change returns only the `Name` property's *value*. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48809321/45375) for background information.

Therefore:

- **[*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)** solution:

```bash
$displayPath = 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\DISPLAY' 
$nonDefaultMonitorNames = 
  Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $displayPath -Exclude Default* | 
  ForEach-Object Name |
  Split-Path -Leaf

$displayDatabasePath = 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\nvlddmkm\State\DisplayDatabase'
$displayDatabaseKeyNames = 
  Get-ChildItem -Recurse -LiteralPath $displayDatabasePath -Include $nonDefaultMonitorNames.ForEach({ $_ + '*' }) |
    ForEach-Object Name |
    Split-Path -Leaf
```

- ***Windows PowerShell* solution**:

Unfortunately, in Windows PowerShell the use of `-Include` and `-Exclude` is subject to many quirks and bugs.
While PowerShell (Core) is no longer plagued by them with respect to the [*registry* provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Registry_Provider), specifically, it unfortunately still is with respect to the [file-system provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_FileSystem_Provider); see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38308796/45375), whose techniques are borrowed for the solution below.

```bash
$displayPath = 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\DISPLAY' 
$nonDefaultMonitorNames = 
  Get-Item -Path $displayPath\* -Exclude Default* | 
  ForEach-Object Name |
  Split-Path -Leaf

$displayDatabasePath = 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\nvlddmkm\State\DisplayDatabase'
$displayDatabaseKeyNames = 
  Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $displayDatabasePath -Include $nonDefaultMonitorNames.ForEach({ $_ + '*' }) |
    ForEach-Object Name |
    Split-Path -Leaf
```

Note:

- The `HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\nvlddmkm\State\DisplayDatabase` registry key is seemingly NVIDIA-specific, so may not be present on all machines.
- `$nonDefaultMonitorNames.ForEach({ $_ + '*' })` potentially creates an *array* of inclusion patterns, by appending `'*'` to the value of / each element of `$nonDefaultMonitorNames`, using the [intrinsic `.ForEach()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#foreach)

Comment: I know, this script only for Windows with Nvidia GPUs. My friend has a laptop with Nvidia gpu and for some reason in his system DisplayDatabase has only generic "CONNECTOR..." and "ADAPTER" subkeys, therefore I have no solution for that case. Maybe it's in some other place which is unlikely, so I tend to belive it's only for pc's

Comment: @SLEStyler, so if you run the code in the answer on your friend's machine what do `$nonDefaultMonitorNames` and `$displayDatabaseKeyNames` end up containing? Are there error messages?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot test his laptop, at least today. But,overall, script can work only if there is a pre-defined folder by Nvidia driver (maybe Windows' driver) in DisplayDatabase such as **GSM5B55_01_07E0_61**, so even if the script can detect "unique" display in `HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\DISPLAY`, it would be impossible to use it in DisplayDatabase entry. I'm sorry if my explanation is the mess, I don't have any knowledge on how all of these entries are created.

Comment: @SLEStyler, but your screenshot shows that such a `key` _is_ present on your friend's machine. So you're saying that there's no corresponding `ACI27EC` key under `HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\DISPLAY`? Note that your original script cannot work with _multiple_ non-default monitors in the latter key - something that the solution in this answer fixes.

Comment: I apologize if didn't make it clear but this screenshot is from a random guy in the internet, who posted this on Reddit, so I don't know if his `HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\DISPLAY` contains **ACI27EC**(I'll try to ask him to post this path). On the contrary, my friend's laptop has "unique" folder in `Enum\DISPLAY` but doesn't contain it in `DisplayDatabase`, in which I need to create  a key

Comment: @SLEStyler, I see. Why do you want to manually create keys there? The _values_ of the monitor-specific  subkeys in `HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\DISPLAY` may contain information of interest too. Separately, it occurred to me that your code will behave differently depending on whether it  is run in _Windows PowerShell_ (`powershell.exe`) or [_PowerShell (Core) 7+_](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md). I've updated the answer to show edition-specific solutions.

Comment: Whole idea of "hack"/script is to create a specific binary in subkey of `DisplayDatabase` ,which suppose to have monitor name. Anyway, thanks for the detailed answer, a lot of useful info

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255698/discussion-between-slestyler-and-mklement0).